# azure cdn: deliver static page from given url from cdn

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-virtual-network

Suppose I own domain name abcd.com. I would like the page abcd.com/some_url - which is static html - to be brought from cdn. In other words the user should not be redirected to any other url, but to receive response from cdn. Is this possible with azure cdn? If so how?

Also if azure cdn can't do that, perhaps others can, any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words the user should not be redirected to any other url, but
>   to receive response from cdn.

We **can't** browse CDN url to access abcd.com/some_url direct.

As a workaround, maybe we can rename some_url to default name and store it to another sub-directory.
**For example**, our website software is Appahce and running on **Linux**. we can do those steps to achieve it.
1. In my lab, I create a new page named `jasontest.html`, a static html. we can browse it via http://xx.xx.xx.xx/jasontest.html
This page file store here `/var/www/html`:

```
[root@jasonvm1 html]# pwd
/var/www/html
[root@jasonvm1 html]# ls
jasontest.html
```

[image]

2.**Copy** `jasontest.html` to `/var/www/html/test1`, and **rename** it to `index.html`.

```
[root@jasonvm1 test1]# pwd
/var/www/html/test1
[root@jasonvm1 test1]# ls
index.html
```

3.Then **add path to Azure CDN endpoint**:
[image]

**Result**:After that completed, we can use `http://jasontest321.azureedge.net` to browse it:
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance:)